# Funcion repetir valores de un arreglo en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Bueno estaba realizando este ejercicio en JS --->

"Crea una función que cambie un array repitiendo sus valores originales (manteniendo el mismo orden).
Por ejemplo, repetirValores([4,”Ulysses”, 42, false]) debiera dar [4,4, “Ulysses”, “Ulysses”, 42, 42, false, false]."

mi codigo es este:

```
function repetirValores(x) {
  var max_length = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    max_length += 1;
    if (max_length = 1) {
      x.unshift(x[i]); // arreglo hasta aqui:  [4,4,”Ulysses”, 42, false]
    }
    if (x[i + 1] != x[i + 2] && max_length <= x.length) {
      x.unshift(x[i + 2]);             // arreglo hasta aqui:  [4,4,"Ulysses", "Ulysses", 42, false]
    }
  }
  return "Arreglo: " + "[" + x + "]";
}
y = repetirValores([4, "Ulysses", 42, false]); // answer:  [4,4, “Ulysses”, “Ulysses”, 42, 42, false, false].
console.log(y);
```

** PERO NO ME ENTREGA NADA ** , SE Cae y termina el programa. Alguien me puede decir como puedo arreglar esto? y resolver el ejercicio? Gracias

Comment: Agrega el código como texto.

Comment: [Porque no es buena idea el código como imágen?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-c%C3%B3digo-vale-m%C3%A1s-que-mil-im%C3%A1genes-c%C3%B3mo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu#answer-3976)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso se puede simplificar usando la función `splice`, te dejo un código con explicación en comentarios:

```js
// El arreglo se modifica por referencia así que no es necesario retornarlo
function repetir(arreglo){
  // Por cada iteración el arreglo incrementará su tamaño por lo que al final
  // será el doble de grande por eso se itera en saltos de 2
  for(let i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i += 2){
  // la función splice insertará un duplicado del elemento en la posición arreglo[i]  en la posición
  // indicada en i + 1
    arreglo.splice(i + 1, 0 , arreglo[i])
  }
}

let arreglo = [1,'hola',false]

repetir(arreglo)

console.log(arreglo)
```

Para entender mejor la función `splice` puedes leer la documentación [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 1):

Entre las muchas posibilidades, se puede crear un array de la misma longitud (usando `.map`) pero trasformando cada elemento de manera tal que quede otro array anidado conformado por dicho elemento repetido, luego podemos usar `.flat` para que el resultado quede de una sola dimensión, este paso duplicará la cantidad de elementos originales.

```js
const arr = [4,"Ulysses", 42, false];

const res = arr.map(e=>[e,e]).flat();

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con una sola línea con el método [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), en cada iteración se agregan los elementos previos [desestructurando](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) el acumulador y agregando dos veces el elemento actual.

```js
let arr = [4,"Ulysses", 42, false];
// Usar reduce para agregar elementos previos con desestructuración
// y duplicar el elemento actual
let dup = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur, cur], []);
// Ver resultado
console.log(dup);
```